# How to use in-memory MongoDB with Rails, Mongoid, and Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rspec-rails

On unit or integration testing, I need to be able to use in-memory mongoDB just for convenience. Am I able to do that? I tried searching for solution and there is no tutorial in how to write mongoid.yml to use in-memory.

Other than that, can I just use default env inside mongoid.yml rather than writing duplicates for both development and production? It is like moving from

```
development:
  client:
    ...

production:
  client:
    ...
```

into

```
default: &default
  client:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid configuration (mongoid.yml in your case) tells the client where the database is. It doesn't configure the database. As such, there are no Mongoid options that would control how the database starts.

If your code uses transactions, your best bet is to create a [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) partition and use `--dbpath` argument to mongod to make it store its data in zram. If you have more memory than you know what to do with you can also use tmpfs.

If your code doesn't use transactions, try `--storageEngine ephemeralForTest`.

mongoid.yml requires configurations for each environment that you are using. This file doesn't have the concept of a default environment (that's decided when you launch the application by Rails), nor can you omit environments. You can however use YAML anchors to avoid duplicating the configuration across environments.